# ZF2 module title in layout

Tags: layout, zend-framework2, viewmodel

I'm having trouble with my layout and viewModel
My design requires that the title set in my viewModel, eg 'blog categories' to be pushed to the layout.

I'm using $this->headTitle() to set the title of the page but i can't get it anywhere else.
because of a lot of changes in the layout per page, i have been forced to use partial in the layout.

single.phtml

```
<?php echo $this->partial('lendstudy/partial/basic/top'); ?>

<div class="container_12 clearfix">
    <div id="content_wrapper">    
        <?= $this->partial('lendstudy/partial/basic/title'); ?> 
        <?php echo $this->content; ?>
        <?= $this->partial('lendstudy/partial/sidebar/left'); ?>
    </div>
</div>
<?php echo $this->partial('lendstudy/partial/basic/bottom');
```

I'm setting the header title in the view
index.phtml from category in a blog module

```
<?php
$title = $this->translate('Categories');
$this->headTitle($title);
?>
<h1><?php echo $this->escapeHtml($title); ?></h1>
<p><a href="<?php echo $this->url('kryuu-blog/category', array('action'=>'add'));?>">Add new category</a></p>
<table class="table table-bordered table-hover">
    <tr>
        <th>Category</th>
        <th>&nbsp;</th>
        <th>&nbsp;</th>
    </tr>
    <?php foreach($categories as $category) : ?>
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo $this->escapeHtml($category->getName());?></td>
            <td>
                <a href="<?php echo $this->url('kryuu-blog/category', array('action' => 'edit', 'id' => $category->getId())); ?>">[Edit]</a>
            </td>
            <td>
                <a href="<?php echo $this->url('kryuu-blog/category', array('action' => 'delete', 'id' => $category->getId())); ?>" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure?')">[Delete]</a>
            </td>
        </tr>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</table>
```

it would then need to be outputtet in the partial/basic/title.

title.phtml

```
<div class="grid_12 page_title">
    <h1><?= $this->headTitle(); ?><span class="subtitle"><?= $this->translate('More information about the Lend Study association') ?></span></h1>
        <div class="page_navigation">
            <?php $partial = array('lendstudy/partial/basic/breadcrumbs', 'default') ?>
            <?php $this->navigation('navigation')->breadcrumbs()->setPartial($partial) ?>
            <?php echo $this->navigation('navigation')->breadcrumbs()->render() ?>
        </div>
</div>
```

how do i do this?

Comment: Are you asking how to access the head title value from the helper, or are you saying you're setting it in a partial but when you try and output it in the layout, it's blank? Your code example doesn't include any reference to the head title helper so it's a bit unclear what the issue is.

Comment: Sorry i have tried to explain it a bit better. tell me if there is more

Comment: The headtitle helper isn't really designed for this - its output includes the `<title>` .. `</title>` HTML tags which might be causing your browser to hide it. If you view the page source is it there?

Comment: correct, it prints <title>News - LendStudy.org - Knowledge to everyone</title> but i only need it to print "News" is there a way to do this?